# How to load google chart after getting response from jquery .post() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am working on a UI where a user chooses both a start and end dates in order to retrieve data. Some of these data are shown in tables and I want to show a google chart related to those data displayed.

When the user finally chooses the dates, i send these two variables by using the `$.post()` function as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>

$('#button-send').click(function() {
    var url_route = "{{URL::action('Controller@general_stats_post')}}";
    var start_date=$('#start_date_i').val();
    var end_date=$('#end_date_i').val();
    var datos = {start_date: start_date, end_date:end_date,_token:_token};
```

Once the send button is clicked, i use the $.post() function which works fine:

```
$.post(url_route, datos, function(data,status){
  if(status=='success'){
    console.log('Dates sent successfully. Now the data retrieved are: '+data);
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if(response.events_types.length === 0){
        console.log('events_types is empty.');
    }
    else{
    console.log('The string for google charts got is: `'+response.events_types+'`');
    /*Here goes the google chart*/

    }
  }else if(status=='error'){
    console.log('Errors found');
  }
 });//end of .post() function
}); //end of onclick button-send
```

The events_types string is, for example:

```
[['Event','Total'],['Workshop',1],['Seminar',1]]
```

which perfectly works in [google's jsfiddles](https://jsfiddle.net/pathros/9rnykh2q/3/).

So, what i have been trying is to put the google chart's drawChart() function inside the {} where the string events_types does exist as follows:

```
        $.post(url_route, datos, function(data,status){
          if(status=='success'){
            console.log('Dates sent successfully. Now the data retrieved are: '+data);
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(response.events_types.length === 0){
                console.log('events_types is empty.');
            }
            else{
            console.log('The string for google charts got is: `'+response.events_types+'`');
            /*GOOGLE CHART*/
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
   console.log('Inside the drawChart() function');
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(response.events_types);
    var options = {
       title: 'My test'
                };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('eventos_charts'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
     }  
            /*END OF GOOGLE CHART PART*/
            }
          }else if(status=='error'){
            console.log('Errors found');
          }
         });//end of .post() function
        }); //end of onclick button-send
```

I have put a console.log message to let me know that the drawChart() has been run. However, I never get that message. So this means the drawChart() function is never run :/ I am stuck.

**Almost working - EDIT**

This is the code that is working... but only if I define the data string manually, that is to say:

```
else{
 console.log('The data string is: `'+response.tipos_eventos+'`');
 var the_string=response.tipos_eventos;
/***** start Google charts:*******/
 //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    console.log('Inside the drawChart() function');
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Evento','Cantidad'],['Taller',1],['Seminario',1]]);//DEFINED MANUALLY

 var options = {
   title: 'The chart'
   };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('events_types'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 drawChart();//Thanks to @FABRICATOR                                

/****  END Google charts: Events types *********/                               
}
```

However, if i tried to get the data dynamically:

```
else{
 console.log('The data string is: `'+response.tipos_eventos+'`');
 var the_string=response.tipos_eventos;
/***** start Google charts:*******/
 //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    console.log('Inside the drawChart() function');
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(the_string);//DEFINED DYNAMICALLY

 var options = {
   title: 'The chart'
   };
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('events_types'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 drawChart();//Thanks to @FABRICATOR                                

/****  END Google charts: Events types *********/                               
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Not an array
```

Any ideas to make it work? What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried just use `drawChart()` instead of `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)`?

Comment: Do you mean to comment out like this `//google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`? Yes, I have tried it, but no luck. How do I call the `drawChart()` function or where should I call it from?

Comment: like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9rnykh2q/4/)?

Comment: Yep, hehe, that helpd a lot! It works if I defined manually  the data string inside the code.☺ However, there're still  errors when I tried to pass the data string,  since i get a `Uncaught Error: Not an array`

Comment: probably because `the_string` is not an array

Comment: From my console.log the string looks indeed like this `[['Event','Total'],['Workshop',1],['Seminar',1]]`. Then how should I pass this data to the drawChart() function?

Comment: I have solved it :) Your comments were very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the easiest solution.
Given that I am using Laravel's ORM (Illuminate/Database), the gotten data comes in json format.

This works for Laravel and Slim framework.

So I pass the variables directly to the view (in Slim):

```
$app->render('home.php',[
        'myArray'=>$myArray
]);
```

Then, inside the view (in this case, Twig view. It should be similar in blade), I get the array and put it in a variable inside the Javascript code:

```
var myArray = {{ myArray|json_encode|raw }};
```

Then I iterate to get each element and add it into the Google chart data array:

```
$.each(myArray,function(index, value){
            //console.log('My array has at position ' + index + ', this value: ' + value.r1);
            data.addRow([value.col1,value.col2,value.col3,value.col4]);
        });
```

And it works now.